# Error: The access path to some JavaScript files on your website is indicated in the URLs from which the redirect is set up

Tags: ajax, scroll, infinite

I am getting a 302 Javascript File Error on a site I am managing. It is using Infinite Ajax Scroll v3.1.0.

The application I use which picked up the error has provided me with this issue description:

"The access path to some JavaScript files on your website is indicated in the URLs from which the redirect is set up.
Because of this, browsers and search engine robots are forced to send an additional HTTP request in order to download the JavaScript file. If there are a lot of files like this on your website, this can significantly increase the page load time."

and its rememedy to fix the problem is:

Indicate the direct path to the JavaScript files, replacing every URL from which the redirect is set up with relevant up-to-date ones.
If you use JavaScript files from an external resource and are not able to replace the URLs, make sure that the URLs point to the correct files.

The url in question is: https://unpkg.com/@webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll@3.1.0/dist/infinite-ajax-scroll.min.js

Would anyknow know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

I haven't tried anything as I am not sure where to begin.